# Dealing with textures of different sizes for Texture2DArray

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to create a Texture2DArray from several textures.
Some textures are 1024x1024, some are 512x512, but some are even 256x512 (uneven width / height).

I can resize from 512x512 to 1024x1024, but I'm not sure what should be done with uneven width / height like 256x512.

What would be the way to ideal with this issue?

Edit: 
This is what it's for: Lars Betram's Advanced Terrain Grass.
This is the part of the docs that deals with the Texture2DAtlas:

[image]

Comment: Depends on what you're doing with those textures.

Comment: @Draco18s I've added a description to my posting.